# How to "Ping" from a Node.js app?

Tags: node.js

I want to ping a server from my node.js app.

Is that doable?

Thanks

Comment: Crafting ICMP messages usually requires root-privileges, so your scripts must run suid root if you're running on unix, and I'm not sure you want that. Or you need to be able to start an external process (i.e. ping) which is suid root, don't know if that's possible in node.js but I suppose it ought to be?

Comment: Nikolaus's approach may get slow if you do it a lot because you are forking processes(relative expensive).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use `exec` to call the system ping command

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("ping -c 3 localhost", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: You can do it this way. But if you do it a lot(concurrently) it is going to be expensive because forking off process is expensive(relative).

Answer (score 27):

[node-net-ping](https://github.com/stephenwvickers/node-net-ping) is an awesome module that uses raw sockets.

And, if you are looking for only raw sockets, the same developer has a module for that too: [node-raw-socket](https://github.com/stephenwvickers/node-raw-socket).

Comment: Any idea how to ping a url using node-net-ping instead of IP address? domain not resolving.

Comment: This does not seem to support ports?

Comment: @OlivUtilo Ping is part of the ICMP protocol, which doesn't have the concept of ports.

Comment: @Bach you could resolve the domain yourself using [`dns.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnsresolvehostname-rrtype-callback)

Comment: Late, but first result on Google, so I wanted to reiterate: You cannot ping ports, and you also cannot ping URLs for the same reason. You can only ping an IP.

Answer (score 10):

I'm author of [ping-wrapper](https://github.com/langpavel/node-ping-wrapper).

It spawn ping and you can listen to events immediately. If process quits, it will be spawn automatically.

Comment: How to install this?

Comment: Use npm. Run `npm install --save ping-wrapper`

Answer (score 9):

Doing ping(programmable) requires root privileges because it requires raws sockets which require root access. You could perform ping following [Gradwohl's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737130/how-to-ping-from-a-node-js-app/4737427#4737427) snippet, but keep in mind that you are forking a new process which is expensive(relatively). If you don't need to do it  a lot(concurrency) this will definitely work :)

To do it in node.js(only) without forking process I think you have a couple of options, which are both hard to implement :()

1. rewrite this [ping python library](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2009/10/30/python-ping/) to node.js and then run program as root user.
2. write a [c++ extension/addon for node.js](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.2.6/api.html#addons-313) using [asio c++ library](http://think-async.com/) for node.js. It also has a couple of examples how to do [icmp ping](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.4.7/doc/asio/examples.html#asio.examples.icmp).

Not (only) using node.js:

1. use [python ping library](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2009/10/30/python-ping/) ran as root and communicate with node.js instance via redis. => **EASIEST to implement.(hardly any work but I think rather fast :))**
2. write c(++) code again using asio c++ but instead of writing node.js extension communicate via [hiredis](https://github.com/antirez/hiredis) with node.js which also uses redis.

As a side-note how to use redis on node.js:

- install redis from http://redis.io
- install the fast [node_redis library](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use my nodejs ping wrapper [yaping](https://github.com/reconbot/node-yaping). One day we will get raw sockets in nodejs and we'll be able to make our own ping packets and lie about our response times. ;-)

This simple function should

- do dns lookups
- ping once
- timeout after 10 seconds
- communicate all the well though out error codes that ping provides
- spawn a child processes out of wedlock

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. The easiest is to use the `ping` command. You can do this by using the `child_process` module.

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const os = require('os');

// Windows: ping -n 1 HOSTNAME
// Linux: ping -c 1 HOSTNAME

function pingHostname(hostname) {
   const result = spawnSync('ping', os.platform() === 'win32' ? ['-n', '1', hostname] : ['-c', '1', hostname]);
   return result.stdout.toString().includes('Reply from');
}
```

Or you can use the `net` module to ping a server.

```js
const net = require('net');

async function pingHostname(hostname) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const socket = net.createConnection(80, hostname);
      socket.setTimeout(3000);
      socket.on('connect', () => {
         socket.end();
         resolve(true);
      });
      socket.on('timeout', () => {
         socket.destroy();
         resolve(false);
      });
      socket.on('error', () => {
         socket.destroy();
         resolve(false);
      });
   });
}
```

### References

- [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html)
- [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)
- [Ping with Option -c on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468135/baccess-denied-option-c-requires-administrative-privileges)

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine,

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exec("ping -c 10 google.com", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```