# b'Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the below error in python when trying to use below line in code:

```
ping = subprocess.Popen(     ["ping", "-c", "3", host],
```

error:

```
b'Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges.\r\n..
```

I am using Atom IDE and windows 10 laptop. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Run it with administrative privileges?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use option `-n` while running the script on **Windows**. The following will work.

```
ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "3", host])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the file as administrator. The command you are trying to use requires administrator privileges to use the -c option. Either remove the -c option, (which I don't know if you need or not,) or run with admin privileges.

Comment: Yes i require -c for my code. how do i run with admin privileges?

Comment: @Venkat In cmd you can do `runas /user:Administrator "python yourcodefile.py"`