# Can I ping a server use k6

Tags: javascript, k6

Can I send a ping request by [k6](https://k6.io/), does it possible?

I know `k6`'s websocket can send a ping request, but it is ws ping and it only support `ws` and `wss`.

Or how can I execute a shell script?

Comment: Looks like k6 is built on ordinary node.js. In that case, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4737130/1048572) should answer both your questions.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. [npm modules](https://docs.k6.io/docs/modules) should help.

Comment: k6 is not built on node.js, it's a distinct JS execution environment  with a different set of APIs from that of nodejs. That said, it does support some node.js modules, namely those that can be "browserified".

Comment: @Yang, may I ask what your use case is?

Comment: @RobinGustafsson Just want to run an example ... I can use `http.get` to replace it.

Comment: k6 looks great and JavaScript looks cool, but I expect it works like go or ruby. I think that will make k6 more handy.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no builtin support for pings or other parts of the ICMP protocol in k6, and it's not possible to execute a shell command or script from a k6 script either.