# How to do ICMP ping in native NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ping, icmp

How about comrades, a few days ago I was trying to ICMP ping to an IP from NodeJS. But as is the rule in the forum, I do not come with empty hands, I have come across some posts even on this website talking about how to do this, but none of them convinces me.

One of the immovable parameters of my project is to avoid the use of NPM / Node-GYP. Therefore the option of using raw-sockets is discarded (unless you can use C ++ code in NodeJS without using things external to node itself).

Also tried (and implemented) the option of using system commands, here you can see my valid implementation for Linux and Windows (I have not tried it on Mac but I am almost sure it works)

```
'use strict';

import { execSync } from "child_process";

class Ping {
    #stdoutToMS (stdout) {
        let res;

        let a = stdout.split('=');
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            res = a[i].split("ms");
        }

        return ~~res[0].split('/')[0].trim();
    }

    ping (host, timeout = 5000) {
        let mstout = timeout / 1000;
        let stdout;

        try {
            if (process.platform === "win32") {
                stdout = execSync("ping -n 1 -l 1 -w " + timeout + ' ' + host);
            } else {
                stdout = execSync("ping -c 1 -s 16 -W " + mstout + ' ' + host);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return false;
        }

        return this.#stdoutToMS(stdout.toString());
    }
};

export default Ping;
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to do this natively in node without using external software, I'd be very grateful if you would tell me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "Ping" from a Node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737130/how-to-ping-from-a-node-js-app)

Comment: @JBaczuk No Sr, based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4741996/15924727 answere of that question i build my small os-based ping library. Im searching for an aproach without node-gyp / npm and without using external software.

Comment: Q: When you say "avoid the use of NPM / Node-GYP", you *DON'T* mean "avoid *ANY* npm package", do you?  SUGGESTIONS: please consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping or https://www.npmjs.com/package/icmp (among others).  If you can't/won't use any npm package whatsoever, please clarify "why".

Comment: @paulsm4 why i should say why? its just a parameter of this project.

Comment: Q: why i should say why? A: Uh, because I asked, and it would be polite to show the courtesy of answering.  Q: Why did I ask?  A: Because if this is truly a "requirement", it seems arbitrary.  It's difficult to write *ANY* non-trivial NodeJS without using at least *ONE* npm package ("Express", "Socket.IO" and "Passport" are pop favorites).  Additionally, I should hope your NodeJS project is using npm packages like Mocha (for testing) or Bower (for builds).

Comment: @paulsm4 Well sorry Sr i didnt mean to insult you, the reason why is becouse i hate how NPM and Node-GYP make all complex, should be something easy for a server side lang like NodeJS be able to do a PING, just a ping. But as i learned, that is not possible.

Comment: Npm is arguably an "essential" tool for NodeJS development.  Like CPAN (for Perl), NuGet (for C#), RubyGems, etc. etc.  Whether or not you like node-gyp: that's up to you.  Have no feelings about it one way or the other.  And whether or not NodeJS supports ICMP out-of-the-box: I would argue that the OpenJS Foundation made the right choice :)

Comment: @paulsm4 i agree that NodeJS run very very good, im a C developer and after several weeks of using NodeJS for some intensive CPU tasks, i can say that is very very smooth. I was just surpriced when i wasnt able to find that ping thing, but thats arright, maybe OpenJS foundation can include raw-sockets as a base node package.

Comment: "because i hate how NPM and Node-GYP make all complex", that would be like a C++ developer complaining how Conan and Ninja make it too complex. Sure they're complex, but once you're over that learning curve you can accomplish a lot more in a lot less time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear you can access a ping equivalent from nodejs without some external code.

Since ping uses the ICMP protocol to do what it does (and it has to use that protocol because it's trying to contact an endpoint that is listening for that) and there is no implementation of the ICMP protocol in nodejs, your only option would be to create your own implementation of the ICMP protocol entirely in nodejs code by getting access to a RAW OS socket and implementing the protocol yourself.  I am not aware of any built-in ability to get a RAW socket in plain nodejs (no external software).

The only examples of ICMP implementation I could find in nodejs ALL use external code to create access to a raw socket.  That seems to be a verification that there is no other way to do it.

There is a module [here](https://github.com/nospaceships/node-raw-socket) that exposes a raw socket, but it uses some native code to implement that.  You can examine its implementation to see what it's doing.

There's also [this library](https://github.com/nospaceships/node-raw-socket) which exposes a RAW socket from libuv to be used within nodejs, but it also uses some of it's own native code.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that i need node-gyp for that, and as i mention in my question, one of the immovable parameters of my project is to avoid the use of NPM / Node-GYP. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani - I'm posting these as examples that show that you cannot get access to a RAW OS socket (upon which you could implement the ICMP protocol which ping uses) without some native code added into nodejs somewhere.  So your answer is "no, you cannot do ping without additional resources outside of nodejs".

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani - Here's [an article](https://blog.ipsumdomus.com/node-js-plain-icmp-ping-implementation-85ac0b319bc2) on implementing ICMP in nodejs which is another example of how it HAS to use an external package to get access to a raw socket.